# ONS Open Geography Portal API Usage for boundaries

Tags: api, united-kingdom

Is it possible to retrieve json/geojson boundaries using the ONS Open Geography Portal API, if so how?

I have got my apikey and gone through the documentation though I am not seeing any mention of boundary data.

If you visit the page http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/afcc88affe5f450e9c03970b237a7999_0

The API dropdown gives links like the ones below:

```
http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/afcc88affe5f450e9c03970b237a7999_0.geojson
```

And the link for a filtered dataset is showing as:

```
http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/afcc88affe5f450e9c03970b237a7999_0.geojson?where=&geometry={"xmin":-7777680.618944722,"ymin":6062179.402493376,"xmax":7113475.483456216,"ymax":8997361.288643364,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}}
```

Visiting the related site http://statistics.data.gov.uk/ you can retrieve a json boundary from a url like below which is more what I was expecting.

```
http://statistics.data.gov.uk/boundaries/E05009755.json
```

Comment: Try this www.boundaries-io.com . A simple API that returns GeoJson bundaries for postal district , sector and unit codes. It does cost $25 bucks a month,check out their Facebook page for example results.....*I work for them*

Answer (score 1):

To get a single boundary you can add a `where` query to the URL, filtering on the relevant geographic code (in this case `wd16cd`).

```
https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Administrative_Boundaries/Wards_December_2016_Boundaries/MapServer/0/query?where=wd16cd=%27E05009755%27&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson
```

This URL gives you a geojson, as in the statistics.data.gov.uk example. To get the ESRI JSON format change `f=geojson` to `f=json`.